# SharePoint Table of Contents Web Part and export/import

Tags: sharepoint, stsadm

After moving a SharePoint MOSS site using stsadm export/import I have found some problems with the Table of Contents Web Part.

If I click the Heading of one of the sections in the Table of Contents web part, for example 'Documents' the page errors as it is still trying to look at a sub-site url from the site that I exported from.

So in the export site, the site was at http://sharepoint/sites/dashboard/

It is now at the root http://sharepoint/

Is this a bug? All the sub-links in the web part work fine, it's just the headings.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Might be one of the properties on the webpart that has a value from where it was exported from (Site?).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.tableofcontentswebpart_properties.aspx